# Walk around a coordinate in circular order to a distance of N

Tags: algorithms

For my development purpose, I need to work on all the 2D coordinates (in whole number) around [0,0] from 0 to N distance. For example, with N=1, I need

```
N0: [0, 0]
N1: [-1, -1] [0, -1] [1, -1] [1, 0] [1, 1] [0, 1] [-1, 1] [-1, 0]
```

The order is important. I want to walk these values in a circular way, starting from 0, incrementing the distance each round.

I first created two for-loops, from -N to N on each axes, but the resulting order is the one as you read a book: from top left to bottom right.

Here's the order I aim (the first coordinate to walk on each circle is not important):

[image: walking order]

Here's a first algorithm I tried, in pseudo code

```
int totalSize = (2*N+1, 2)*(2*N+1, 2)
Vector2[] coordinates = new Vector2[totalSize]
int index = 0
coordinates[index++] = new Vector2(0, 0)
for (int d = 1; d <= N; d++) {
    for (int x = -d; x <= d; x++) {
        coordinates[index++] = new Vector2(x, -d)
        coordinates[index++] = new Vector2(x, d)
    }
    for (int y = -d+1; y <= d-1; y++) {
        coordinates[index++] = new Vector2(-d, y)
        coordinates[index++] = new Vector2(d, y)
    }
}
for (int i=0; i<coordinates.Length; i++) {
    print(coordinates[i])
}
```

But:

- It seems too cumbersome. I don't like the creation of a scructure that retains the coordinates. And 4 for-loops seems not optimized.
- The order of the circles is ok, but the order inside each circle is not the one I described.
- I have the feeling trigonometry can help me, but I can't see how to implement it on discrete values

Any idea?

Comment: In the illustration, why not go to [-2,1] after [-1,-1]? Then go to [-2,0]. That would be more consistent and, hence, easier to specify, understand and implement.

Comment: Yes, I totally agree. As I said, the order of the first coordinate in each circle is not important.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in a stateless manner.

Here is python code that generates the infinite walk:

```
def circular():
    yield (0,0)
    x,y = -1,0
    while True:
        yield (x,y)
        if x < 0 and 0 <= y < -x:
            y += 1
        elif y > 0 and x < y:
            x += 1
        elif x > 0 and y > -x:
            y -= 1
        elif y < 0 and x > y:
            x -= 1
        elif x < 0 and y < -1:
            y += 1
        elif x < 0 and y == -1:
            x -= 1
            y += 1
```

Comment: I implemented something base on your answer, and it works. But It seems to me a bit cumbersome, I wonder if there wasn't any algorithm with less if-else statements.

Comment: You gave an algorithm with no if-else statements.